# Patterns in transcendental functions with irreducible quotients and limit L with $0<L<∞$, like $\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}-\sqrt{x^2-1}}{\ln{(x+1)}-\ln{(x)}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

I was looking for functions with the above stated properties and also whose numerator and denominator both tend to $0$ as $x\to\infty$, then I came up with $\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}-\sqrt{x^2-1}}{\ln{(x+1)}-\ln{(x)}}\right)$ after some trial and error with CAS and graphing software. Its limit is $1$ as $x\to\infty$ and also note that it is transcendental. The rules I came up with for finding this function are rather vague, but they go something like:

- the numbers in the function should all be $x$'s or similar pairs, like square and square root.
  **Edit**: I discovered another such transcendental function: $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{\sqrt[x]{x+a}-\sqrt[x]{x-b}}{x^{-2}}\right) = (a+b)$, so the below rule has to go.
- <s>if a minus sign is involved between outer terms, then it should be in both the numerator and the denominator.</s>
- The Factorial (or the Gamma function) doesn't seem to work, probably because of its unwieldy steepness.
- Other vague rules...

What are some examples of different types of such functions? What are the patterns you observe in them?

Comment: These limits looks like derivatives. Look at the limit definition of derivative, and see if you can use it here.

Comment: A little more more on point. To get this behavior at $x = \infty$ as in your example, you can take any two functions $f$ and $g$ that are differentiable at $0$ with $g'(0) \ne 0$ and look at $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{f(1/x) - f(0)}{g(1/x) - g(0)}$$ which will satisfy your conditions, with $L = \frac{f'(0)}{g'(0)}$.