# prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt[x]{x+1}-\sqrt[x]{x-1}}{x^{-2}} = 2$

Tags: calculus, limits

**Edits**:
time 1: I have observed that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{\sqrt[x]{x+a}-\sqrt[x]{x-b}}{x^{-2}}\right)=(a+b)$

time 2: $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{\sqrt[x]{x+a}-\sqrt[x]{x-b}}{\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}{x^{-n}}}\right)=(a+b)=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{\sqrt[x]{x+a}-\sqrt[x]{x-b}}{(x^2-x)^{-1}}\right)$

---

I was playing with CAS in GeoGebra to find a particular kind of functions, one of which is the above one.
The numerator and the denominator both tend to zero, so it makes sense to apply the L'Hospital's rule. But, each of the terms is infinitely differentiable and the derivatives of the terms of the numerator are
\begin{align*}
    f(x) &= \sqrt[x]{(x+1)} \\
    \dot{f}(x) &= f(x)\left(\frac{1}{x(x+1)} - \frac{\ln(x+1)}{x^2}\right)
\end{align*}
which looks like kind of a reoccurrence relation, and it continues indefinitely. And the denominator only gets worse from there $-$

\begin{align*}
    {f(x)} &= x^{-2} \\ 
    \dot{f}(x) &= -2x^{-3} \\
    \ddot{f}(x) &= 6x^{-4}
\end{align*}

It doesn't yield any useful simplification. How do you proceed from there?

---

This question is an extension to [another](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4829273/general-patterns-in-functions-with-non-reducible-quotients-and-a-limit-l-with) question of mine.

Comment: "I am still editing the question. Do not down-vote!" You should do this before posting your question.

Comment: Also there is no question in the body of your text.

Comment: Why do you $\frac{\text{whatever}}{x^{-2}}$ instead of $x^2 \cdot \text{whatever}$?

Comment: @Dominique It captures that they both approach the same value at the same rate, which is easier to understand for me, rather than saying that one diverges to infinity, the other goes to zero and their product approaches a constant value. That is why the L'Hospital's rule is generally stated the way it is. Also look at my second edit, the function with an infinite sum in the denominator. This is the actual form of the function, though reducible, and it is in already in the way you apparently like.

Comment: I've changed my upvote to a downvote, because OP has changed the question. They should, instead, try to understand the current answers and apply them to the new question, and ask the new question as a new question on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use that:

- $\sqrt[a]b=e^{(\ln b)/a}$, and
- $e^u=1+u+o(u)$
  as $u→0$,
  and
- $\ln(1+u)=u+o(u)$.

(For the precise definition of the notations  $o()$ and $\sim$, see for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis#Definition.)

As $x→∞$, $\sqrt[x]x=e^{\frac{\ln x}x}\to e^0=1$ and
$$\begin{align}\sqrt[x]{x+1}&=\sqrt[x]x\sqrt[x]{1+1/x}\\&=\sqrt[x]x\left(1+\frac{\ln(1+1/x)}x+o\left(\frac{\ln(1+1/x)}x\right)\right)\\&=\sqrt[x]x\left(1+\frac1{x^2}+o\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)\right)\end{align}$$
and similarly,
$$\sqrt[x]{x-1}=\sqrt[x]x\left(1-\frac1{x^2}+o\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)\right)$$
hence
$$\begin{align}\sqrt[x]{x+1}-\sqrt[x]{x-1}&\sim \frac{2\sqrt[x]x}{x^2}\\&\sim\frac2{x^2},\end{align}$$
q.e.d.

Update following your two edits:

- Needless to say, the very same ideas can be used to prove more generally your "edit 1$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{\sqrt[x]{x+a}-\sqrt[x]{x-b}}{x^{-2}}\right)=a+b$".
- Your edit 2 doesn't add deep improvements. Your initial denominator $x^{-2}$ can indeed be replaced by a lot of various expression which can easily be proved asymptotically equivalent to it.

Answer (score 1):

By [Newton's generalized binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton%27s_generalized_binomial_theorem), for all $x>1,$

\begin{align}
\\
(x+1)^\frac{1}{x} = x^\frac{1}{x}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^\frac{1}{x}\\
=x^\frac{1}{x}\left(1+ \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) + \frac{1}{2!} \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^2 \left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \left(\frac{1}{x} - 1\right) + \frac{1}{3!} \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^3 \left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \left(\frac{1}{x} - 1\right)\left(\frac{1}{x} - 2\right) + \ldots \right)\\
\\
=x^\frac{1}{x}\left(1+ \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^2 + \frac{1}{2!} \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^3 \left(\frac{1}{x} - 1\right) + \frac{1}{3!} \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^4 \left(\frac{1}{x} - 1\right)\left(\frac{1}{x} - 2\right) + \ldots \right).\\
\\
\end{align}

Similarly,

\begin{align}
\\
(x-1)^\frac{1}{x} =x^\frac{1}{x}\left(1 - \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^2 + \frac{1}{2!} \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^3 \left(\frac{1}{x} - 1\right) - \frac{1}{3!} \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^4 \left(\frac{1}{x} - 1\right)\left(\frac{1}{x} - 2\right) + \ldots \right).\\
\\
\end{align}

Both series converge absolutely by the ratio test, since, for all $n\in\mathbb{N},\ \left\lvert \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right\rvert < \frac{1}{x}<1 .$

Thus we may add the terms of the two series in any order we wish. Noticing the cancellation of every other term, we get:

$$ (x+1)^\frac{1}{x} - (x-1)^\frac{1}{x} = 2x^\frac{1}{x} \left(\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^2 + \frac{1}{3!} \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^4 \left(\frac{1}{x} - 1\right)\left(\frac{1}{x} - 2\right) + \ldots \right). $$

We see that, $$\frac{2x^{\frac{1}{x}}}{x^2} < (x+1)^\frac{1}{x} - (x-1)^\frac{1}{x}<2x^{\frac{1}{x}}\left(\frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{1}{x^2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left( \frac{1}{x^2} \right)^n \right) = 2x^{\frac{1}{x}}\left(\frac{1}{x^2} + \left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{x^2-1}\right) \right).$$

Dividing through by $\frac{1}{x^2},$ and applying the [Squeeze Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) by letting $x\to\infty$ yields the desired result.

Answer (score -1):

Take x common from (x+1) to get 1 + $\frac{1}{x}$ and similiarly for x-1 to get 1 - $\frac{1}{x}$. This leaves the numerator with $\sqrt[x]{x(1+\frac{1}{x})} - \sqrt[x]{x(1-\frac{1}{x})}$. Take $x^{\frac{1}{x}}$ out of the numerator (which for $x \to \infty \to 0$ to finally get $x^{\frac{1}{x}}(\sqrt[x]{1+\frac{1}{x}} - \sqrt[x]{1-\frac{1}{x}})$. Now use the fact that as $x \to \infty \implies \frac{1}{x} \to 0$ and so you can use binomial approximation ($(1+y)^n \approx 1 + ny$) on $\sqrt[x]{1+\frac{1}{x}} - \sqrt[x]{1-\frac{1}{x}}$ to get $({1+\frac{1}{x}})^{\frac{1}{x}} - ({1-\frac{1}{x}})^{\frac{1}{x}} \approx (1 + \frac{1}{x} \cdot \frac{1}{x}) - (1 - \frac{1}{x} \cdot \frac{1}{x}) = \frac{2}{x^2}$ (here we are taking only second order terms and while we could take 3rd order terms, when divided by $x^{-2}$ they will be of the form $\frac{1}{x}$ and it's higher powers which $\to 0$ for $x \to \infty$. Like the second term (next terms contain even higher orders of $\frac{1}{x}$) in the binomial approximation of $(1+y)^n$ is $\frac{(n)(n-1)y^2}{2}$ and when we use it in the above expression, we get an additional term of $\frac{(\frac{1}{x})(\frac{1}{x} - 1) \frac{1}{x^2}}{2}$ which is of the order of $\frac{1}{x^3}$ and when divided by $x^{-2}$ gives the order $\frac{1}{x}$ which as said above $\to 0$ for $x \to \infty$

So now divide by denominator $x^{-2}$ to get limit = 2

Comment: Your binomial approximation should not be an equality, and anyway does not seem legit here.

Comment: @AnneBauval I think this answer uses a correct approach. However, too many details are absent for it to be convincing.

Comment: I only agree with your 2nd sentence. Those $\approx$ (not much better than the previous $=$) are lacking of a precise mathematical meaning, and of a proof. I would therefore not qualify this as a "correct approach".

Comment: What I mean by "correct approach" is that this approach can be made rigorously correct. I'm almost finished doing this on paper, and will post my rigorous version of this answer shortly.

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not actually understand the problem in my answer (why is it not rigorous?). If you could edit my answer (or post your own with the same method) and make it more rigorous then it will be helpful for me to understand the missing details in my answer

Comment: The problem is mainly your $(1+y)^n \approx 1 + ny$, where the $\approx$ has no precise meaning, and which is for $n$ fixed hence cannot be applied to $n=1/x$.

Comment: I didn't raise it to the power of e first and directly used binomial but except for that, I don't think there is any difference in your solution and my solution is it? And as for the approximate sign, you used o(u) notation while I used approximate sign because I am not well versed in higher level mathematical terminology yet. And the binomial theorem one, I would use the Taylor series but since we need only the first term, we can directly use binomial theorem for a good approximation so as to reduce the work to get to the answer